# LinkedIn API: The token used in the OAuth request has been revoked (Web Social Login)

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

Here's how I try to get the user data from LinkedIn:

```
$config = array(
    'appKey'       => 'appKey',
    'appSecret'    => 'appSecret',
    'callbackUrl'  => 'callbackUrl'
);

@session_start();

$linkedin = new LinkedInOAuth2( $config );

if ( $_GET['login_type'] == 'linkedin_login' ) {

    $scope  = array( 'r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile' );
    social_js_redirect( $linkedin-getAuthorizeUrl( $config['appKey'], $config['callbackUrl'], $scope ) );

} elseif ( ! empty( $_GET['code'] && ! empty( $_GET['state'] ) ) ) {
    $data   = $linkedin->getAccessToken( $config['appKey'], $config['appSecret'], $config['callbackUrl'] );

    if ( ! empty( $data['access_token'] ) ) {
        $linkedin->getProfile(); // Get user data from linkedin to add to database

    } else {
        // Invalid Authorization
    }
}
```

This is the error code that adds into the database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [errorCode] => 0
            [message] => Then token used in this request has been revoked by the user.
            [requestId] => xxx
            [status] => 401
            [timestamp] => 1540051999134
        )

)
```

NOTE: By check my PHP code you will understand that LinkedIn successfully get the access token

Answer (score 0):

could you try adding a delay of 5-6 seconds after obtaining the token. Most problems i see on stackoverflow/github regarding this problem has to due to the fact that LinkedIn doesnt seem to activate the token that it gives immediately, so waiting a bit helps.